# android blocked in Canvas.drawPath method

Tags: android

I'm developing a hand-writing application, which using TextureView for displaying.
As we need to operate the Shape Object, I use a LinkList to store the shape objects.
And I use a Drawing Thread for the rendering the shape objects, which will use the Canvas.draw methods.
The problem is, when writing shapes on the application, sometimes the Drawing Thread will be blocked by method ***Canvas.drawPath(Path, Paint)***, and the application stop rendering the shape objects.

Comment: I use Path for storing the writing traces. And display using Canvas.drawPath method.